# Node cannot find module '@helpers/...'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to using TypeScript and wanted to use it in a new backend project, however, when I'm trying to use the import node crash by telling me it can't find the module

Here's some code that can be relevant and the config file for TypeScript

./tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "./build",
        "allowJs": false,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

./src/app.ts

```js
import express from 'express';
import 'dotenv/config';
import UserController from './controllers/user';
import User from 'models/user';

// Code for the app goes here
```

./src/controllers/user.ts

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import express from 'express';
import checkArgs from '@helpers/checkArgs';

// Class of the Controller goes here

export default UserController;
```

I'm not sure what I am missing but I think it has something to do with the tsconfig

What I saw online told me to set a NODE_PATH environment variable but it doesn't do anything (I've tried by setting it to './' when running in the build folder, and setting it to 'src/' and 'build/' when running in the root folder)

Edit:
Here's the directory structure:

```
admi-erp/
├── build
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── user.js
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── checkArgs.js
│   │   └── permissions.js
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── user.js
│   ├── app.js
│   └── server.js
├── src
│   └── (same structure as the build folder)
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

Comment: `"@helpers": ["./src/helpers"]`

Comment: It's the compilation that doesn't work now,
`src/controllers/user.ts:3:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@helpers/checkArgs' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: maybe You try to use it like: `"@your-project-name/helpers": ["src/helpers"]` ?  In my apps I use it like “@libs/helpers” and put it to “libs/helpers”, when my apps are in: “apps/users-service/src”

Comment: From what I understood, the "paths" keys are more likely to be what's using at the start of the import, like a shorthand instead of doing things like "../../../../../../helpers/checkArg"

Comment: yes, so try to do like @app/helpers

Comment: got the same error when building

Comment: have You changed in Your code to import from “@app/helpers” or what You defined in tsconfig

Comment: yups, I've tried and got the error, I shouldn't have?

Comment: should. Then need more info about directory structure

Comment: I've added it in the post

Comment: in this case avoid using aliasing, use as regular import by path. Name aliasing is useful if You separate things out of Your app structure.

Comment: I would have prefered to use aliasing but if I have no other choices, I'm going for the no-alias way so. Thanks for the time!

Comment: "Cannot find module '@helpers/checkArgs'" - how about if you add the extension (I assume `checkArgs.ts`)?

Comment: I don't think it would work since after the build the .ts file become .js files, and the js interpreter should be able to determine the extension

Comment: @Architek please do as in docs: https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353